# How to change behavior of the link in Firebase email verification email to return back to the app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an issue with an Android app I'm working on.
By default, when the user clicks the link in Firebase email verification email, he is taken to a web page which says his email address is now verified. 
Instead of this, I would like to achieve that when the link is clicked, the app opens up again. How is that possible?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992992/how-can-i-redirect-back-to-my-app-after-the-user-has-verified-their-email-using?

Comment: Yes I did, but it is for iOS and I do not fully understand how should I do it on Android.